# .htaccess doesn't redirect properly

Tags: php, jquery, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have this autocomplete script fron jquery.
It fetches details from a database and then displays to the user, when the user clicks on a particular result..he is taken to a page :- page.php?id=(id received via fetch in autcomplete).

I have a .htaccess redirect which **had** to work like this.
Suppose the id is 2, then it would automatically redirect to *products/2* .
But for some reason, it doesn't seems to be working.

Here is the autocomplete :-

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
      source: "search.php",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {


        log( ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.label :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.actor );
        window.location.href = 'product_display.php?id=' + ui.item.value;
       // document.testForm.action = "pretravel.php?id="+ui.item.value;
        //document.testForm.submit();
      }
    });
  });



  </script>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.+)$ product_display.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**product_display.php page**

```
<?php
include 'dbconnector.php';
$id=$_GET['id'];
$id=htmlspecialchars($id);
$query = "SELECT productname from products where productid = '" . $id . "' order by productname";
$result=mysql_query($query,$db) or die (mysql_error($db));
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['productname'];

?>
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your javascript typo, Change this

```
window.location.href = 'product_display.php?id=' + ui.item.value;
```

To

```
window.location.href = './product_display.php?id=' + ui.item.value;
```

Then only the complete url comes.
**[Update]**
Your rewrite rule is like this

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.+)$ product_display.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So you url must come like this

```
// sample url    http://example.com/products/{id}
//then code must be
 window.location.href = './products/' + ui.item.value;
```

**[update]** Try using **mysqli** instead of *mysql* to connect database for good security.

Comment: Doesn't seems to be working.
Still redirects to product_display.php?id=the id upon clicking.

Comment: Updated still not working ? Then try to solve one by one. First try to access url without javascript give some existing id and check .htacess working correct or not. Ex http://example.com/products/1. If not then provide folder and files structure.

Comment: This worked perfectly.
Is it possible that I show the product name instead of the ID and even receive the product ID somehow.(So that I can fetch the contents)

Comment: Im not clear about your question. you can give product name but you have to change php code and sql query. And if you don't mind accepting my answer will gain may reputation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47440/discussion-between-ankur-and-shanoop)